# ssh keeps asking for new password

Tags: ssh, openssh

I want to login to a Linux box with openssh installed. After each login ssh requests me to change my password because it is outdated. How can I prefent this? The server system is created with buildroot.

What can I do to find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Do you actually change your password when this happens? Does the password change work? Is the system's clock accurate?

Comment: Yes i tried to change it. It also changes on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually seems like this, that with buildroot the support for UsePAM is disabled. I don't know if this IS the reason why it's now working, but i guess so. I choose to use authentication via a public key and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is pretty vague, but it sounds like whoever set up the server you are using has fubar'd the password aging settings.  Check the `/etc/shadow` file.